# PNG image does not display transparent

Tags: html, css, image

I got a **.png** image, but it does not show transparent(it shows with the background squares too)

I have tried to change the type of the picture and the picture itself.

```
<div id="header">
<img src="lowback.jpg" alt="LowBack Logo" >
```

I want to make it transparent, with no background.Just the actual pic.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Are you positively sure that the image is transparent? There's no way to get background squares in a browser unless the image file has actually printed squares in it. And the JPEG file format does not support transparency at all.

Comment: Your file is "lowback.jpg" ... jpg which normally does not support transparency.

Answer (score 0):

try add css to img:

```
img { background: transparent; }
```

or inline:

```
<img src="lowback.png" alt="LowBack Logo" style="background: transparent;">
```

shure that your png file have transparent background??
In your code is a jpg, this format dont work with transparency!